# Problems With py2app on a Mac

Tags: python, installation, py2app, traceback

I've recently started to code python, and have written my first applications that I would like to give to some of my friends in the form of a single application, NOT a python script. After scouring the internet, I decided that py2app was the best idea. I've tried to install py2app in many ways, and I felt like it was finally installed. I tried to create a setup.py and this is what I got back.

```
John-Smith-MacBook:~ johnsmith$ py2applet --make-setup main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/py2applet", line 2, in <module>
    from py2app.scripts.script_py2applet import main
ImportError: No module named scripts.script_py2applet
```

Please help!

Cheers.